# Xcode 13 Swift project - Archive build giving me error on Objective C Bridge

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode

I have a Swift project running on Xcode 13. The project builds perfect without any error, but when I try to Archive then I get error that is related to the Objective-c Bridge.

[image]

I have the my .h bridge file created correctly. That's why when I build it works perfect. This is only happening when I want to Archive for a publish.

This is the content of my .h bridge file:

```
#ifndef TestApp_TestApp_Bridging_Header_h
#define TestApp_TestApp_Bridging_Header_h

#import "ECSlidingViewController.h"
#import "DSLCalendarView.h"
#import "UINavigationController+Orientation.h"
#endif
```

I also have under my Target - Build Settings, the reference to the Bridge file:

[image]

Any clue what can I could try. I need this to get ready for publish.

Comment: Put the same bridging header path in a release.

Comment: Ohhh yes that could be the problem. Let me try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to set the bridging header path in the release section as well.